# Bucle con XMLHttpRequest no me funciona

Tags: javascript

Con este bucle voy comprobando si la página de destino me arroja un 1 o nada (página en blanco), **pero siempre me entra en los dos IFs**, no lo entiendo. ¿Qué está mal?

Yo he testeado la página de destino (const url) en el navegador y si estoy logeado me arroja 1, pero sino se queda en blanco.

```
var i = 1;
var response = 0;

function myLoop () { 
   setTimeout(function () { 
                const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                const url='url/get_session'; //Devuelve 1 o nada (página en blanco)
                Http.open("GET", url);
                Http.send();

                Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
                    response = Http.responseText.replace(' ','');
                    if(response == '1'){ console.log('In: '+response); }
                    if(response != '1'){ console.log('Out: '+response);
                        //location.reload();
                    }
                }
      i++;
      if (i < 10000000) {  myLoop(); } 
   }, 5000)
}

myLoop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que compruebas el valor del resultado antes de que te llegue, por eso te entra primero en Out y luego en In:

El valor de la [propiedad `readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) puede ser uno de los siguientes:

- 0 **UNSENT**  Cliente creado, `open()` no se ha llamado aún.
- 1 **OPENED**  `open()` ha sido llamado.
- 2 **HEADERS_RECEIVED**    `send()` ha sido llamado, `headers` y `status` están accesibles.
- 3 **LOADING** Descargando; `responseText` puede tener datos parciales.
- 4 **DONE**    Operación completada.

Por tanto lo que te falta es comprobar que la operación se ha completado antes de leer responseText:

```
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (Http.readyState === 4) {
    response = +Http.responseText.replace(' ',''); //el + transforma a número
    if(response === 1){ 
      console.log('In: '+response); 
    } else {
      console.log('Out: '+response);
      location.reload();
    }
  }
}
```

Aunque la solución más sencilla sería no usar `onreadystatechange`, sino `onload`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('UNSENT', xhr.readyState); // readyState es 0

xhr.open('GET', '/api', true);
console.log('OPENED', xhr.readyState); // readyState es 1

xhr.onprogress = function () {
    console.log('LOADING', xhr.readyState); // readyState es 3
};

xhr.onload = function () {
    console.log('DONE', xhr.readyState); // readyState es 4
};

xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Gracias! Eso era.